# How to filter a list of files having a common part in the file name and containing some text?

Tags: regex, grep

The following command works fine and gives me the list of **files containing some text in the content** -

```
grep -rl "Text in content" .
```

The following command also works fine and gives me the **list of all the files containing two text segments in the file name** -

```
ls -lrth | grep "profiling" | grep "20170714_07"
```

So, I tried to pipe the output of the 2nd second above to the input of the 1st command -

```
ls -lrth | grep "profiling" | grep "20170714_07" | grep -rl "aerospike" .
```

But, I am getting the following file in the output as well, which does not contain both "profiling" and "20170714_07" -

```
./aero_debug_10_20170714.log
```

Please help, I am a newbie with grep.

Comment: You put a `.` at the end, after `"aerospike"`, remove it.

Comment: That is because I want to search only in the current directory.

Comment: I think you are searching through a list of what `ls` returned. I doubt you need the `.` here. I tried it, and it did not bring any results, while without it, it returned expected matches. Note you may try to run a single `grep` command. If `profiling` comes before `aerospike` and the date comes last, use `ls -lrth | grep "profiling.*aerospike.*20170714_07"`

Comment: @SandeepanNath it would be better if you give sample list of files and what you wish to filter.. parsing `ls` is not advisable... could probably solved using `glob` without needing grep at all... and not sure what you suppose the final `grep -rl` would do.. if you are trying to pass directory name from previous `grep`, you'd need `xargs`...

Comment: Hm, here is [a nice post about `ls` parsing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "aerospike" comes in the content of the files, not in the name.

Comment: You should add these details to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had already added. Now made those parts bold.

Comment: @Sundeep edited my question a bit. Please see if it helps.

Comment: sorry, it is still unclear to me.. give us sample files and contents to work with... or at least, show some output lines from `ls -lrth | grep "profiling" | grep "20170714_07"` and describe in detail what you want to do further

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a single command, you'll need more than `grep`.  If you're in a Unix environment that provides the `xargs` command, you could do the following:

```
ls -1 | grep "profiling" | grep "20170714_07" | xargs grep "aerospike"
```

`xargs` takes a list of filenames (one per line, which is why the `ls` commands is changed to `ls -1`, which lists the filenames only in that form), and then executes the command following it (`grep "aerospace"` in this case) for each of those files.

*Note*: if filenames have spaces in them, you might consider using a different command to solve your problem: `find`, with a command line similar to the following:

```
find . -name "*profiling*20170714_07*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "aerospike"
```

(the only issue is that this wouldn't find filenames where the date string was first in the filename, but you could use another `-name` option in the `find` command to search for those if you needed).